# How do I do to solder the adapter in the port and still use the same usb port without ruining the notebook?

Tags: usb, wireless, adapter, laptop, usb-hub

I have a laptop that the wireless network card does not work, but I do not want to use my usb input for putting an external adapter, my idea is to open the laptop and solder the adapter inside the notebook in the usb port and still use the port externally.

How do I do to solder the adapter in the port and still use the same usb port without ruining the notebook?

Comment: If you solder the adapter to your USB port internally, you can't use that port externaly anymore. USB doesn't allow you to just piggy-back devices like that.

Comment: there exist USB hubs for a reason...

Comment: Just solder a USB hub into the netbook

Comment: @PlasmaHH yeah, space is a abundant resource in those things anways.

Comment: Because there is the usb hub, then it would be the same idea only internally, the problem is that I have no idea how a usb hub works, I did some research it seems to just use a capacitor, but I do not want to risk it, so I asked the question .

Comment: A USB hub is more than just a capacitor. It is an active device that interacts with the USB host device to enumerate the downstream devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea "to open the laptop and solder the adapter inside the notebook in the usb port and still use the port externally" won't work, a USB  port can't be just forked into two devices. Since you failed to provide any other details about your "a laptop", all advises to solve your problem will be speculative.

There could be several variants to embed a WiFi USB device into a laptop, although I doubt very much that mechanical restrictions will allow you to do this. You can find another USB device in your laptop that you don't want to use, like a fingerprint sensor, modem, or webcam. Then you can re-direct corresponding wires to your new USB adapter. However this would require a bit of reverse engineering of connectors and very fine soldering skills and fine-tip soldering iron.

If the system has the M.2 connector and it already is used for, say, SATA, it is theoretically possible to re-use the USB2 wires from M.2 connector if they are implemented, and if BIOS support is not preventing the use of the slot if SATA is already there. Again, this would require having fine bi-axial micro cables to implement, and exceptional soldering skills.

In short, an attempt to do this kind of rework will likely render your laptop ruined. It is likely a time to get a new one.

Answer (score 2):

What you want **cannot work**.

Even if you would succeed in mounting the external USB in the laptop and connecting it to the USB port then that USB port will be **in use by that adapter**. So you will not be able to use that USB port for anything else.

You somehow have to create an **extra** USB port and connect the adapter to it. This can be done using a USB hub, these connect to one (laptop) USB port and make 2, 3, 4 or more new ports available.

If your laptop has a (free) mini PCI-E slot available you could use an adapter [like this](http://www.ebay.nl/itm/Mini-PCIe-mPCIe-to-USB-2-0-Port-Card-Support-Adapter-Reader-USB-WiFi-Bluetooth-/361619544478?hash=item543234599e:g:F0gAAOSwCQNWgzrO):

[image]

To create an extra USB port. (I use these to hide the wireless mouse receiver inside my laptop and not use an external USB port).

But maybe the Wireless Network Card sits in a PCI-E slot, in that case you can just buy a new one to replace to broken one, they're not that expensive.

Comment: I'm using this port for a ssd

Comment: No you're not because an SSD is either in an M.2 slot or Msata. Probably PCI-E SSDs do exist but I have never seen them. PCI-E SSDs generally use the M.2 slot as well as M.2 can support PCI-E as well as SATA and even USB. If there is only one slot like this in your laptop and it has an SSD in it then your laptop has no suitable slots.

Comment: I did not know this difference, I would take the slot from the wireless network card, put the ssd, and use the USB adapter for the wireless network.